# TableView reloading too early

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

I'm running into a weird issue where my `tableView` is reloading too early after retrieving **JSON** data.  The strange thing is sometimes it reloads after getting all the required data to fill the `tableView` and other times it reloads before it can acquire the data.  I'm not entirely sure why it's doing this although I do notice sometimes the data is returned as nil. Here is what I use to retrieve the data:

```
  var genreDataArray: [GenreData] = []
  var posterStringArray: [String] = []
  var posterImageArray: [UIImage] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GenreData.updateAllData(urlExtension:"list", completionHandler: { results in

      guard let results = results else {
        print("There was an error retrieving genre data")
        return
      }
      self.genreDataArray = results

      for movie in self.genreDataArray {

        if let movieGenreID = movie.id
        {
          GenrePosters.updateGenrePoster(genreID: movieGenreID, urlExtension: "movies", completionHandler: {posters in

            guard let posters = posters else {
              print("There was an error retrieving poster data")
              return
            }
            for poster in posters {

              if let newPoster = poster {
                if self.posterStringArray.contains(newPoster){
                  continue
                } else {
                  self.posterStringArray.append(newPoster)

                  self.networkManager.downloadImage(imageExtension: "\(newPoster)",
                    { (imageData)
                      in
                      if let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data){
                        self.posterImageArray.append(image)
                    }
                  })
                  break// Use to exit out of array after appending the corresponding poster string
                }
              } else {
                print("There was a problem retrieving poster images")//This gets called sometimes if the poster returns nil
                continue
              }
            }
          })

        }
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.genresTableView.reloadData()//This is reloading too early before the data can be retrieved
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Did you purposely not include `reloadData()` in your completion block? The retrieval is likely being done asynchronously so reloading the data might happen before the data is fully obtained.

Answer (score 1):

The data is being retrieved asynchronously, and thus your table view can sometimes reload without all the data. What you can do is have the table view reload at the end of the asynchronous data retrieval, or you can reload the cells individually as they come in instead of the whole table using

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowNumber, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
```

Comment: I haven't seen it done this way before, I'll give it a shot

Comment: You just need to make sure that you have the data for that cell before you reload it

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS-:**

```
var genreDataArray: [GenreData] = []
      var posterStringArray: [String] = []
      var posterImageArray: [UIImage] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    genredataArray.removeAll()
    posterStringArray.removeAll()
    posterImageArray.removeAll()

                   NOW HERE CALL YOUR CLASS FUNCTION AS ABOVE     
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in that case, you should use

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    for data in json as! [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
    {
    //take data from json. . .
    }
    //reload your table -> tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

You should get the main queue of the thread.